# Are there arbitrarily sparse "lattices" in negatively curved symmetric spaces?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, gr.group-theory

Let $X$ be a negatively curved symmetric space. In other words, $X$ is one of the four examples: a hyperbolic space, a complex hyperbolic space, a quaternionic hyperbolic space or the hyperbolic Cayley plane.

Let $B\subset X$ be a compact set (wlog, a large ball). Does there always exist a subgroup $\Gamma$ of the isometry group of $X$ such that $X/\Gamma$ is a compact manifold and the images of $B$ under $\Gamma$ are disjoint (i.e. $B\cap\gamma B=\emptyset$ for every nontrivial $\gamma\in\Gamma$)?

**Remark:** It would suffice to find just one (for each $X$) residually finite discrete co-compact group of isometries. I am sure there is one but I don't know where to look. (Or maybe they all are residually finite?)

**Meta-proof:** If the answer is negative, then, for some of the model geometries (in some dimension), all compact manifolds with this local geometry are "uniformly thin" - all injectivity radii are bounded above by some universal constant. Such a wonderful fact would be widely known.

Comment: Malcev's theorem:  Every finitely generated group of matrices is residually finite.

Comment: Thanks! One stupid little thing remains: why do co-compact subgroups exist?


Comment: Sergei: The fact that cocompact lattices exist doesn't just follow from abstract nonsense type arguments, in fact, Margulis showed that they don't exist for some homogeneous spaces $G/H$ with semisimple $G$ and non-compact $H.$ So some version of Borel and Harish-Chandra is necessary (if I'm not mistaken, the mere existence part is due to Borel alone).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The examples are arithmetic groups, constructed in general by [Borel and Harish-Chandra](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=147566). 
See also [Dave Witte Morris' preliminary book](http://people.uleth.ca/~dave.morris/books/IntroArithGroups.html). 
However, examples in hyperbolic and complex hyperbolic spaces probably go back further to the study of quadratic forms.

For hyperbolic lattices, one can take a quadratic form over a quadratic number field (such as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$), which
is Lorentzian at one place, and definite at the other places (such as $x_1^2+\cdots +x_n^2-\sqrt{2} x_{n+1}^2$), and take the group of matrices $\Gamma$ in $GL(n+1,\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}])$ which preserve this quadratic form. Then [Mahler's compactness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahler%27s_compactness_theorem) (cf. Witte Morris) implies 
that the quotient $\mathbb{H}^n/\Gamma$ is compact. Then by Selberg's Lemma and residual finiteness (as Greg points out, Malcev's Theorem), you may find a torsion-free subgroup 
of finite-index with as large injectivity radius as you like.

For hyperbolic and complex-hyperbolic spaces, there are other examples which don't come from the arithmetic construction (in fact, most hyperbolic surfaces and 3-manifolds are not arithmetic). These are attributable to [Gromov and Piatetski-Shapiro](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=932135) in the hyperbolic case in all dimensions, and there are finitely many examples in the complex hyperbolic case (at least for $\mathbb{C}$-dim >1) going back to Deligne and Mostow (see also [Thurston's paper](http://www.msp.warwick.ac.uk/gtm/1998/01/p025.xhtml)). However, Gromov and Schoen have shown that quaternionic and Cayley-hyperbolic lattices are all arithmetic, so the Borel Harish-Chandra construction is complete in these cases.

Addendum: Related to Protsak's comment, there is a simple example of a negatively curved homogeneous space which has no lattice action. This is Thurston's "9th geometry", which is excluded as a geometry precisely for this reason. One can take the double warped product metric $$ dr^2 + e^{2a r} dx^2 + e^{2b r} dy^2, $$ for $a,b >0$. When $a=b$, this gives hyperbolic space. But when $a\neq b$, the sectional curvatures are $-a^2, -b^2, -ab$. This has a solvable transitive group of isometries, so is homogeneous. But using the solvability, one may see that there is no cocompact action. (Remark:  when $a=-b$, this gives sol geometry).

Comment: Interesting example, but the isometric restriction is a bit strong. It feels complementary to the result I quoted, where $G$ is semisimple and there is no obvious metric (since $H$ is noncompact).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't read your comment carefully. I assumed you meant a homogeneous space with a negatively curved metric (because of the nature of the question), and I didn't notice the requirement that G be semisimple. 

Answer (score 3):

Let me give an explicit example for the Poincare disk in dimension 2. In the disk model, just take the regular $4g$-gon centered on the origin. Identifying opposite sides, we get a compact surface of genus g. The polygon is a fundamental domain for the group $\Gamma$ 
generated by $b_1...b_{2g-1}$ with

$b_k=\pmatrix{\cosh(a) & e^{ik\pi\over 2g}\sinh(a)\cr e^{-ik\pi\over 2g}\sinh(a)& \cosh(a)}$

where a is defined by $\cosh(a)=1/\tan(\pi/4g)$. The value of a is in fact equal to the radius of the maximal disk contained in the fundamental domain. This is also the distance from any side of the 4g-gon to the origin. It goes to infinity with g, so we are done.

The Gauss-Bonnet formula tells us that surfaces of a given genus have a bounded volume, hence cannot contains arbitrarily large embedded balls. Hope that helps.